# What Is it's value?

Tags: numerical-methods

$\dfrac{(2+1)(2^2+1)(2^4+1)\cdots(2^{32}+1)+1}{2^{60}}=?$
I don't know what simple trick is there to use to solve it. Any idea?

Comment: I have difficulties understanding the dots. Is it  $$\dfrac{(2+1)(2^2+1)(2^4+1)(2^6+1)\cdots(2^{32}+1)+1}{2^{60}}$$ or $$\dfrac{(2+1)(2^2+1)(2^4+1)(2^8+1)\cdots(2^{32}+1)+1}{2^{60}}?$$

Comment: @Mathematician42 - probably the second - powers of powers of $2$

Comment: @Henry: Ah sure, the first factor doesn't make any sense in the first progression. Stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{(2+1)(2^2+1)(2^4+1)\cdots(2^{32}+1)+1}{2^{60}}\\
=\dfrac{(2+1)(2-1)(2^2+1)(2^4+1)\cdots(2^{32}+1)+1}{2^{60}}\\
=\dfrac{(2^2-1)(2^2+1)(2^4+1)\cdots(2^{32}+1)+1}{2^{60}}\\
=\dfrac{(2^4-1)(2^4+1)\cdots(2^{32}+1)+1}{2^{60}}\\
=\cdots\\
=\dfrac{((2^{32})^2-1)+1}{2^{60}}=\dfrac{2^{64}-1+1}{2^{60}}=2^4=16$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: multiply $(2+1)(2^2+1)\cdots(2^{32}+1)\,$ by $\,(2-1)$ and use $(2^k-1)(2^k+1)=2^{2k}-1$.

Comment: Very nice, chapeau.

Comment: Yours answer also says something but I was lazy to check. I have o accept K.vijays answer. +1 btw

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

- Calculate

  - $(2+1)+1=2^2$
  - $(2+1)(2^2+1)+1=2^4$
  - $(2+1)(2^2+1)(2^4+1)+1=2^{8}$
- Spot the pattern, give yourself a hypothesis, prove it by induction
- Apply to the case in the question and then divide by $2^{60}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The pattern is easy:

$$(2^1+1)(2^2+1)=2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0$$
$$(2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0)(2^4+1)=2^7+2^6+2^5+2^4+2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0$$
$$\cdots$$

---

Even simpler with

$$2+1=2^2-1,$$
$$(2^2-1)(2^2+1)=2^4-1,$$
$$(2^4-1)(2^4+1)=2^8-1,$$
$$\cdots$$